# Offline git clone Drone CI using proxy as Nexus

Tags: kubernetes, drone.io, disconnected-environment

I am running :

- drone-server on top of kubernetes
- and drone-kubernetes-runner to dynamically provisioning runner as pods.

After investigation, i found the Pod YAML of each runner defines the 1st step "git clone" using the image `drone/git`.

I am running the pipeline in offline environment. I have to specify `nexus.company.local/drone/git` instead of `drone/git` to avoid fetching from the public registry.

I search everywhere, but no way.
Even `image_pull_secrets` is valuable for explicit steps that i can define.
It's NOT valuable for implicit steps like the "clone" step

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could disable the automatic cloning and add an explicit step, specifying your own image with the nexus mirror origin.

For example:

```
kind: pipeline

clone:
  disable: true

steps:
  - name: clone
    image: nexus.company.local/drone/git
```

Comment: that's really cool! thanks! .. but what about leveraging the default clone command and args which depends from event to another ?

Comment: You can use the official drone/git image mirrored to your repo. Make sure to provide all environment variables that are required and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
DRONE_RUNNER_CLONE_IMAGE=nexus.company.local/drone/git
```

REF: https://docs.drone.io/runner/docker/configuration/reference/drone-runner-clone-image/